# Can't bundle Monaco Editor To disconnected environment

Tags: reactjs, webpack, monaco-editor

Trying to bundle monaco editor into my app using `react-app-rewired` and `webpack`.
I'm getting 404 on the file: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/monaco-editor@0.33.0/min/vs/loader.js

Here is my configuration of `config-overrides.js`:

```
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    config.plugins = [
        ...config.plugins,
        new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
          languages:['sql'],
          publicPath: "/build/"
      })
    ]

    return config;
}
```

I can see the workers files are bundled in my app, but I can't load them.
In addition, I tried to see the `publicPath` to '/' or remove it totally, but the behavior is the same.